# How to compile a 32bit hello world on alpine?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld, alpine-linux

Given a simple hello world code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  puts("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

On a 64bit alpine linux installation I tried to compile it as 64bit and as 32bit.
The first works fine, but the second is missing 32bit libraries:

```
~ # gcc -Wall hello.c 
~ # gcc -Wall -m32 hello.c 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../libssp_nonshared.a when searching for -lssp_nonshared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libssp_nonshared.a when searching for -lssp_nonshared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lssp_nonshared
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Because I found no obvious way to fix this, I fetched the 32bit version of gcc, libgcc, and musl-dev extracted to a local directory and set LIBRARY_PATH:

```
~ # LIBRARY_PATH=usr/lib/gcc/i586-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0:usr/lib gcc -Wall -m32 hello.c 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/crtbeginS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/crtendS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
~ #
```

This partly fixed the issues, but gcc still tries the 64bit libraries first and finds tries to find the 64bit crt files.

So what is the correct way to compile a 32bit binary on alpine linux?

---

To make the last problem more clear, look at this:

```
~ # LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp gcc --verbose -Wall -m32 hello.c 2>&1|grep LIBRARY_PATH
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/:/tmp/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/5.3.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

If I only set some LIBRARY_PATH, the compiler internally adds other directories to it. Especially it also prepends the "wrong" system directory, which contains the 64bit libraries. Therefore it uses the wrong crt libs and therefore the last error above.

I either need the correct alpine package (and not care about how it works), or I need to understand how to change that first path added internally by gcc.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I used above, when the error messages started.

Comment: It seems the linker does not look for the 32 bit libs, but the 64 bit libs. I have not used that kind of down-compilation, but maybe you have to tell the linker also to use 32 bit mode (and lib-paths)?

Comment: The "default" installation of alpine linux does not bring any 32bit libs and I found no obvious package to install those. That's why I tried the manual way using LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @michas if there are no 32-bit libraries in the system, you can't expect the linker to make them out of thin air. You need to find desired libs version and put those in library path.

Comment: How exactly did you set `LIBRARY_PATH`.  If using bash, did you remember to `export`?  You could try using `-L` option to gcc instead.

Comment: Oh, come on. Please read that question more carefully. I gave the exact commands with all options and environment variables. You can try it yourself by simply copy and pasting the given command. The problem with both `LIBRARY_PATH` and `-L` is, that the compiler inserts them *after* its wrong system library path. Please add `--verbose` to see the resulting internal `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `gcc -v` on alpine gcc is compiled without multilib support:

```
--disable-multilib
```

While multilib is enabled on debian:

```
--with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib
```

Multilib support is required for the `-m32` to work reliable. Therefore the default compiler on alpine is really not suited for compiling 32bit binaries.